# Meteor react drag and drop

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I am making an app where I have to drag  tag and drop on the specific images for tagging so how do I get the id of the target DIV where I drop my tag or will please explain me about how does this all work for drag and drop,

I just want to know the id of dragged tag and target DIV where i drop this tag.

thanks

Comment: toit john po rahexa

Comment: sodhna pardaina hamlai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the id of dragged element in the window inside the eventListener of dragged event and access the id in the eventListener of dropped event.

**For dragged element**

```
dragged(e){
  window.selectedLabelId=$(e.target).attr("id")
}

<label ondragstart={this.dragged}>some label</label>
```

**In dropped element**

```
dropped(e){
  console.log(window.selectedLabelId)
  window.selectedLabelId=null
}
<img src="/imgsrc" ondragend={this.dropped}/>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery-ui there is callback on drop

```
$( ".selector" ).droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
     var id = $(event.target).attr('id');
  }
});
```